# How do I enlarge LibreOffice menu font?

Tags: libreoffice

Specifically LibreOffice on Lubuntu 18.04.
Have tried various OS system settings
+Obviously LO settings,
all in vain.

Answer (score 3):

No need to remove Libreoffice, just

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk2
```

create 2 files in `~` w/ the following contents:

.gtkrc-2.0:

```
include '/home/j/.gtkrc.my'
```

.gtkrc.my:

```
style "gedit" {font_name = "12"}
widget_class "*" style "gedit"
gtk-font-name = "13"
```

Log out and log in. the 1st number controls system (menu|tab) font size, the 2nd applications' font size, provided they have something like `libreoffice-gtk2` installed (this depends on the application). Adjust Libreoffice menu icon size under Tools > Options > View

Answer (score 1):

Setting the dpi in the X system changes the reported physical screen size. the standard libreoffice package and others consider this value and will adjust their menu, toolbar, and font sizes accordingly.

```
$ xrandr --dpi 200
```

The typical value is 96, so a value of 200 will report that a line one inch long requires 200 pixels instead of 96.

Note: I just tried another answer and removed libreoffice then installed libreoffice-gtk3. Libreoffice-gtk3 ignores the dpi setting, but respects gjk3 settings. If you use gtk, I feel that libreoffice-gtk3 is better looking than the normal libreoffice package magnified by xrandr --dpi.

Note: This question specifically asks about lubuntu, which uses the QT graphical library. This is the same library used by kde, therefore removal of libreoffice and installation of libreoffice-kde5 might assist in this situation. I did not try it because I use openbox and gtk.

Answer (score 0):

In my case on Kubuntu 21.04 (upgraded from Kubuntu 20.04) helped to uninstall everything using *libreoffice* in the name, including configurations, and installing a single package *libreoffice*.